# How to train two half cheetha opengym environments using same DDPG ( neural networks) simultaneously in reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

How to train two half cheetha opengym environments with single neural network of DDPG in reinforcement learning? Objective is to implement single DDPG (one main actor, one main critic, one target actor, one target critic neural networks) network training multiple half cheetha environments, half cheetha has 6 continous action space and 17 continuous state space.

How the input/output layer Neurons will look while training two half cheetha environment simultaneously, for two half cheetahs it would be 12 out neurons(6 each) in that case.For fully connected network the inputs of one half cheetah env will influence other half cheetha and vice versa.

Comment: You should check out the rl library stable baselines3 and vectorized environments. Basically, you can wrap your environment so that instead of spawining just one copy of half cheeta environment, multiple copies can spawn to train a single reinforcement learning algorithm (such as DDPG). This can be done with a few lines of code, without having to change neither the environment nor the neural network.

Comment: Thanks Raoul..   I was wondering what is the best way to modify the DDPG neural networks that it give o/p to train two separate half cheetah environment simultaneously. Our requirement is multiple half cheetah getting trained simultaneously.. .

Comment: No problem! The DDPG network will stay the same as if you were training it in a single half cheetah environment. What happens is simply that the network, instead of being trained with experiences (states, actions and rewards) coming from only one environment, is trained with experience from multiple environments. Imagine the workflow like: 1) get state1 from first environment 2) get state2 from 2nd environment 3) action1=model.predict(state1) of the first env 4) action2=model.predict(state2) of the second environment.  5) nextstate1, reward1, done1 = env1.step(action1) and so on ...

Comment: Hi Raoul. If we do so like this then the weights of single neural networks  will get overlapped between two environemnts?   workflow like: 1) get state1 from first environment 2) get state2 from 2nd environment 3) action1=model.predict(state1) of the first env 4) action2=model.predict(state2) of the second environment.

Comment: Exactly! Since you are exploring more of the state of the environment, more "diverse" experience is used to train the neural network (which is a good thing!). Imagine that your human brain is shared among two identical humans, that are living in a similar space. Both humans can do the same things, but since they are in two different places, they will experience different things. Therefore your brain will see and learn more things more quickly (since you have two bodies instead of one). That's the same thing in RL. You train on multiple env to increase the amount of experience that you receive